# How to mock return value without mocking object?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am performing a unit test for `addPortfolioTrans` method below. But I'm not sure how do I mock the method `validateSellAction(portfolioTrans)` without mocking `PortfolioTransServiceImpl` class.

`PortfolioTransServiceImpl` class:

```java
@Override
public PortfolioTrans addPortfolioTrans(PortfolioTrans portfolioTrans, long portId, String username) {
    
    StockWrapper stockWrapper = portfolioHoldService.findStock(stockSym);
    if ((stockWrapper.getStock() == null || stockWrapper.getStock().getQuote().getPrice() == null)) {
            portfolioTrans.setErrMsg("Stock Symbol is invalid, unable to get stock price. Save transaction failed.");
            return portfolioTrans;
    }

    if (portfolioTrans.getAction().equals(ConstantUtil.SELL_ACTION)) {
        sellActionCheck = validateSellAction(portfolioTrans);
    }
}
```

I wanted to do something like this below for my test class. But I am not sure how to do it without mocking an object. My objective is to return a `-1` value after mocking the `validateSellAction` method.

`TestPortfolioTransServiceImp` class:

```java
@InjectMocks
@Autowired
private PortfolioTransServiceImpl portfolioTransServiceImpl;

@Mock
PortfolioHoldService portfolioHoldService;

@Test
void testAddPortfolioTrans_sellSuccess() {
    Long portId = 2L;
    String username = "user1";

        //edited and added this portion
        Stock stock = new Stock("MSFT");
        stock.setStockExchange("NasdaqGS");
        stock.setName("Microsoft Corp.");
        StockQuote stockQuote = new StockQuote("MSFT");
        stockQuote.setPrice(new BigDecimal("280.04"));
        stock.setQuote(stockQuote);
        StockWrapper dummyStockWrapper = new StockWrapper(stock);
        
        //i have other dependencies with other services
        when(portfolioHoldService.findStock(anyString())).thenReturn(dummyStockWrapper);

    PortfolioTrans portfolioTransObj = new PortfolioTrans();
    portfolioTransObj.setStockName("Microsoft Corp.");
    portfolioTransObj.setAction("SELL");
    portfolioTransObj.setNoOfShare(50);
    portfolioTransObj.setStockSymbol("MSFT");
    portfolioTransObj.setStockExchg("NASDAQ");
    portfolioTransObj.setTransPrice(new BigDecimal("269.81"));

    PortfolioTrans result = portfolioTransServiceImpl.addPortfolioTrans(portfolioTransObj, 0, username);

    // wanted to mock return value below, but not sure how to do it without mocking object
    when(validateSellAction(portfolioTrans)).thenReturn(-1);

    // assert statements below
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for can be achieved by "spying" on an object - [creating a spy object based on an actual object instance](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) (thanks to **@Jeff Bowman** for the clarifying comment). It allows you to verify calls to certain methods, but also partially redefine the object's behaviour, for example mocking a single method, while preserving behaviour of all the others. You can read about Mockito spies [in the docs](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html) or many other sources on the Internet.

What you have to do is either annotate the field with a `@Spy` annotation, call the `spy(...)` method explicitly or use a `@SpyBean` [annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/mock/mockito/SpyBean.html), if you're using Spring (which I assume might be the case, since there's `@Autowired` over a field).

The approach is called [partial mocking](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#partial_mocks). You can also use mocks and tell Mockito to call actual methods implementation instead of mocking all the rest (by using [doCallRealMethod](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doCallRealMethod()) or `thenCallRealMethod` described in the docs link above).

Comment: I think partial mocking is what the OP is asking for, but be careful: I would describe spying as creating a spy _based on_ an instance but not _wrapping_ an instance, since Mockito will actually [create a new subclass instance](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/4.6.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) with overridden methods and then copy instance state into it. [This can also matter for anonymous inner classes.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33656249/1426891)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I actually DO NOT want to call the real method validateSellAction(portfolioTrans). I want to mock it to return a -1 value. 

On top of this, i wanted to mock other methods from other dependencies also. Edited the code above.

Comment: Is it worth challenging why you need to mock `validateSellAction`?  In general, unit tests that assume less about internal implementation (and just focus on input/output) better survive later changes.  Does `validateSellAction` make some external service call, and if so could you mock that instead?  Or if it has a side effect, could you extract that side effect into a service that you inject into this class?

Comment: @MarkPeters Ok, that is one way of resolving. I think that helps. Thanks. I can actually mock validateSellAction using another service, e.g. when(portfolioTransDao.validateSellAction(portfolioTransObj)).thenReturn(-1);